# Magento2 2.3.5 Saved Payment Methods still shown in customer dashboard navigation

Tags: magento2

I removed the Payment Agreements link succesfully using 
''

But I still get a link to "Saved billing agreements"

Does sombody knows how to get rid of this link?

Using Magento 2.3.5-p1

DId not find something.

Please let me know.

Comment: '<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>'

Comment: THis is the code I used for removing Billing Agreements

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it myself.
If you want to get rid of this link, you have to use:
`<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>`

This is credit card stuff.
So now I have removed all I do not wnat to have in my customers dashboard.